# how to scrape html content of div using all matched class

Tags: php, dom, web-scraping

The site i need to scrape is having structure like

```
<span class="address">
<p>...</p>
<h4>...</h4>
....
</span>
```

All i need is html inside of

```
<span class="address"></span>
```

What i am using is a code from google.

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile('www.site.com');
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
$nodelist = $xpath->query( '//*[@id="main_center"]/div/div/div[2]/div/span[15]/p[6]' );

foreach ($nodelist as $n){
 echo $n->nodeValue."\n";
}
```

Its only giving me content without html,i need have all html so that i can filter them according to my needs.

Please provide suggestion,
Thank you.

Comment: Anybody who can help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
<?php

  $html = new DOMDocument();
  @$html->loadHtmlFile('http://php.net/manual/de/domdocument.savehtml.php');
  $xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
  $nodelist = $xpath->query( '//footer' );

  foreach ($nodelist as $n){
    echo $html->saveHtml($n)."\n";
  }
```

see: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php
This is tested and works fine.

Do you outout direct to a Browser?
Then look at the generated source code, the html tags will not be displayed in a brwoser ...

hth oli

Comment: could you please tell me about what xpath i need to use there in my code also, because i need all contents of html which is having <span class="address">

Comment: o.k i have used //*[@class='address'], that is correct xpath, but your above code still giving me only contents, not with html.

Comment: htmlentities also works, but your first answer gave me what i needed most. Thank you very much Oliver, God bless you!